# My Google activity taking hours to update

Tags: google-account, google

I always use My Activity in my Google account which comprises all activity made with my phone for that day. It used to update quite quickly after each interaction on my device such as apps used, phone usage, etc. However, it is updated every 6-8 hours now.

Does anyone know why and how to fix this? I don’t believe I have changed any settings on my device or Google account.